# Parallax mid-way through page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am triggering a parallax effect on an element half-way through my page. As I am attaching this to `scrollTop()` it is causing the element to jump when initialised.

```
var feedPos = $(".feed").offset().top - 100;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= feedPos) {
        $(".feed").css("top", 150 - $(window).scrollTop() / 100);
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe put a css rule on the feed with a transition on top so the change will animate?  Other than that, you should consider throttling/debouncing your logic as the scroll event fires a lot.  Also to that effect, you don't want to be performing dom lookups in a scroll event as they degrade performance for something that happens a lot.  Put your logic in an IIFE, scope cache your lookups, and use those in your handler.

Comment: Different browsers handle the scroll event differently.  Using that event this way is going to have some crazy results.  If at all possible, try to keep all of your styling in the css not the javascript.

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciated. This is the way I've always handled functionality such as this. Could you provide an example of 'throttling/debouncing your logic'? @Taplar

Comment: Are you just trying to apply a "parallax like effect" without doing actual parallax?  Or do you have parallax set up but don't want it to kick in until you get part way through a page?

Comment: Well, all I'm doing for this particular section is scrolling an element slightly slower than its background. @nurdyguy

Comment: Well, a "poor man's throttle" is to set a boolean, `isAnimating` and when you are in the process of scrolling, set it to true and when you finish set it back to false.  Then, when more scroll events come in they first check if animation is in progress and if so they just exit and don't do anything.  I would also add a jQuery animate instead of just changing the 'top' so you can control it more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines may help you.

For the html, I made 100 divs of 80px tall with some text, and 25 divs of 80px call with a background color and bottom border, just so you could see the difference in scrolling speed.  I used c# mvc with razor to generate them but however you want to create those divs is fine.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="fast">
        @for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            <div>@i. This is row @i</div>

        }
    </div>

    <div class="slow">
        @for (var j = 0; j < 25; j++)
        {
            var r = 255 - j;
            var g = 127 + (int)(.5 * j);
            var b = 10 + j;
            <div class="color" style="background-color:rgb(@r, @g, @b)"></div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

For css I use scss but again, you can create the css however you want.

```
#container {
    height: 700px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;

    .fast {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        div {            
            height: 80px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

    .slow {
        width:100%;        
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        div {            
            height: 80px;
            width: 100%;
            opacity: .3;
            border-bottom:1px dotted white;
        }
    }
}
```

And no the javascript:

```
var isAnimating = false;
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#container').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e)
    {
        if (!isAnimating)
        {
            isAnimating = true;
            e.preventDefault();

            var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY;                
            var $this = $(this);

            console.log(delta);


            var newFast = parseInt($this.find('.fast').css('top'), 10) + delta;
            var newSlow = parseInt($this.find('.slow').css('top'), 10) + delta / 4;

            if (newFast > 0)
                newFast = 0;
            if (newSlow > 0)
                newSlow = 0;

            console.log(newFast + "   |   " + newSlow);

            $this.find('.fast').animate({ top: newFast + 'px' }, 100);
            $this.find('.slow').animate({ top: newSlow + 'px' }, 100, function () { isAnimating = false; });

        }
    });

});
```

Note:  This only handles mouse wheel scrolling, not drag bar scrolling.  Actually, I didn't create a scrolling div so all of the scrolling you see is from the wheel.  You can make a `.scroll(...)` event also but those tend to be very finicky from one browser to the next.  Even with this there is some jitteriness.  Messing with scroll events can be a tricky thing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Makes perfect sense. :)

Comment: As a side note, using a Boolean like that works really well when doing things like infinite scroll and type-ahead searches.  You don't want to be shooting off too many ajax calls at once.